# Problems with tokenizing text for deep learning

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to perform deep learning on multi-label text classification, but I can't get my text data turned into tokens. It gives me the following error:

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Data --> https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20211007hyXKqXNO

This is my code:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

from sql.sql_import import import_data
from preprocessing.transcription_preprocessing import TranscriptionPreprocessor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

# Import data
df = pd.read_csv(r'product_data.csv')

# --- Data preprocessing --- #

# Define preprocessor class
tp = TranscriptionPreprocessor()
# Preprocess text
df['text_clean'] = tp.transform(df['text'])

# Define dataframe to only include relevant columns
df = df.loc[:,['text_clean','TV','Internet','Mobil','Fastnet']]

# Sum the number of labels per text
sum_column = df["TV"] + df["Internet"] + df["Mobil"] + df["Fastnet"]
df["label_sum"] = sum_column

# Remove texts with no labels
df.drop(df[df['label_sum'] == 0].index, inplace = True)
#df.drop(df[df['label_sum'] == 3].index, inplace = True) #<-----------  overvej
#df.drop(df[df['label_sum'] == 4].index, inplace = True) #<-----------  overvej

# Define dataframe with labels
df_labels = df.loc[:,['TV','Internet','Mobil','Fastnet']]

# Sum of each label
df_labels.sum(axis=0)

# Distribution of multi-labels
df['label_sum'].value_counts()

# Make train and test data
train, test = train_test_split(df, random_state=42, test_size=0.2)
label_train, label_test = train_test_split(df_labels, random_state=42, test_size=0.2)
X_train = train['text_clean']
X_test = test['text_clean']

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=50000)
X_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(X_train, mode='binary')
X_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(X_test, mode='binary')
label_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(label_train,num_classes=4)
label_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(label_test,num_classes=4)
```

Comment: you have to cast one of the values to the other type. either `str(your_number)` or `int(your_string)`. Then you will be able to compare them.

Comment: Do you mean X_train = str(X_train)?

Comment: if that's the one you're having issues with, yes.

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't help - produces same error

Comment: which line does produce the error?

Comment: X_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(X_train, mode='binary')

Comment: what's the value inside `X_train` ?

Comment: Its text, dtype: object

Comment: then it sounds like it should be numbers. Sorry, but I can't help you more